# RASA chatbot not working poperly when integrated with slack

Tags: chatbot, slack-api, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I have developed a restaurant chatbot using RASA NLU and RASA CORE. From command line (powershell) it works fine. I have integrated it with slack, slack is acting as interface. However from slack its not working as desired. Two actions are getting triggered at the same time. Putting screenshot for your reference.

[image: slack]

Also adding image from powershell where it is working fine.

[image: powershell]

Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please add the relevant part of your code to the question. Otherwise it will be very hard for the community to figure out a solution. Also, please embed a text copy of your images in the question. At least the 2nd image is very difficult to read. thank you

Comment: Hi Erik, PFB the github link having code. https://github.com/getVishalSingh/restaurantSearchChatBot.

Comment: You shouldn't upload a zip file to GitHub, you put your code there directly.

Comment: Please embed your code as text in the question